# How to optimize code execution time in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a project in scala which simulates the economy in my country. I wrote a messaging system that people send to the environment and receive back. I used spark to parallelize sending messages based on agentId. I also wrote a simple test for measuring code execution time. Running code takes approximately 30 seconds for 50 people. I need to decrease the code execution time. What can I do in this situation? Which approach can help me?

I used combineByKey to combine every agent's messages based on their key-id. I want to use groupByKey, reduceByKey and others. But what else I can do for decreasing the code execution time? Here the messaging part below.

```
@transient def run_until(until: Int) {
      println("RESUME Simulation " + this);

      var messages: List[Message] = List()

      // loop starts here
      vaxt {
        while (timer <= until) {
          if (!GLOBAL.silent) println("timer = " + timer);

          if (GLOBAL.RUN_SPARK) {
            //          s.setReceiveMessages(mx.getOrElse(s.id, List()))
            simsSpark = simsSpark.mapValues { s =>
              s.handleMessages()
              s.run_until(timer)._1.asInstanceOf[SimO]
            }.cache()

            var dMessages: RDD[(AgentId, List[Message])] = simsSpark.flatMap(_._2.getMessages).map(x => (x.receiverId, x)).combineByKey(
              (message: Message) => {
                List(message)
              },
              (l: List[Message], message: Message) => {
                message :: l
              },
              (l1: List[Message], l2: List[Message]) => {
                l1 ::: l2
              }
            ).cache()


            // Environment answers immediatley for the next step
            val envMessages: RDD[(AgentId, List[Message])] = dMessages.filter(_._1 == ENVIRONMENT_ID).flatMap(_._2).flatMap(handleEnvMessage).map(x => (x.receiverId, x)).combineByKey(
              (message: Message) => {
                List(message)
              },
              (l: List[Message], message: Message) => {
                message :: l
              },
              (l1: List[Message], l2: List[Message]) => {
                l1 ::: l2
              }
            ).cache()

            // Append environment to messages: important merge both together (groupByKey otherwise elements may be duplicated at join afterwards)
            dMessages = dMessages.filter(_._1 != ENVIRONMENT_ID).union(envMessages).groupByKey().mapValues(_.flatten.toList)
            dMessages = dMessages.cache()

            simsSpark = simsSpark.leftOuterJoin(dMessages).mapValues { x =>
              x._1.setReceiveMessages(x._2.getOrElse(List()))
              x._1
            }.persist()


            if (!GLOBAL.silent) {
              simsSpark.foreach(_._2.stat)
              println()
              println()
            }

          } else {
            messages = messages.filter(_.receiverId == ENVIRONMENT_ID).flatMap(handleEnvMessage) ::: messages.filter(_.receiverId != ENVIRONMENT_ID)

            val mx = messages.groupBy(_.receiverId)
            messages = List()

            market = market.map(m => {
              m._2.setReceiveMessages(mx.getOrElse(m._2.id, List()))
              m._2.handleMessages()
              m
            })

            messages = market.flatMap(_._2.getMessages).toList ::: messages

            sims = sims.map {
              s =>
                s.setReceiveMessages(mx.getOrElse(s.id, List()))
                s.handleMessages()
                s.run_until(timer)._1.asInstanceOf[SimO]
            }
            messages = sims.flatMap(_.getMessages) ::: messages

            if (!GLOBAL.silent) {
              for (s <- sims) s.stat;
              println();
              println();
            }
          }

          timer += 1;
        }
      }
      //loop finish here


      println("STOP Simulation " + this);
    }
```

Comment: You should analyze the UI. Also I find the code a bit too long, not sure we can see only the relevant parts

Comment: But I have not any UI. I run the code only in the terminal and see result also there

Comment: Does Spark connect on a UI ? Usually `http://localhost:4040`

Comment: @GulnarNecefova: I think BlueSheepToken didn't mean the UI of your application, but rather the [Spark Web-UI](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-webui.html); it provides some diagnostic information, maybe there's something useful there.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin You are completely right, thanks for the clarification !

Comment: This code isn't relevant to debug as it's current state. I invite you to look into writing an MVCE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example so we can help you with it.